# Ingress rule for multiple paths not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

here is the situation: I have 2 deployments running for sonarqube (for different use cases) linked to 2 different services and I am redirecting traffic through Ingress path based routing.

```
metadata:
  annotations:    
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonar-namespace
spec:
 rules:
  - host: sonar.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: sonar-service-1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /sonarqube/
      - backend: 
          serviceName: sonar-service-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /sonarqube-two/
```

I am able to access UI page under /sonarqube and under /sonarqube-two/ as well but whenever I am trying to take any action (say installing new plugins, creating new user etc) it's redirecting me to login page every single time. Could someone please help me this? Let me know if any information is required from my side.

Comment: i think it is may problem due to ssl or tls certification. Check this out:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect is your application is stateless or stateful ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's a stateful application, backed with EBS volume.

Comment: are you using stateful deployment ?

Comment: kind: StatefulSet

Comment: maybe some session problem i think

Comment: I got it. The issue was with cache and cookies. Opened a new browser and cleared all cache and cookies and it started working. Thanks for pointing out the session problem, it helped me to navigation to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Sonarqube the path in which it is running, if you're not using the default path /.

You can set that by setting

```
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

in `$SONARQUBE-HOME/conf/sonar.properties`

Taken from the official documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/ (Starting the Web Server)

An alternative approach would be to use subdomains instead of paths to host it (e.g. sonar1.example.com and sonar2.example.com). Then you wouldn't need to modify your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for replying. sonar.web.context=/sonarqube is there in sonar.properties file and that's why I am able to access web UI with both the paths but when I try to take any action (like creating new user etc) it's redirecting to login page every time.

Comment: Okay, was just the first guess.
Do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: The issue was with cache and cookies. Opened a new browser and cleared all cache and cookies and it started working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never thought that issue would be with cache and cookies! Opened a new browser(firefox) and cleared all the history, cache, and cookies and after that, all started working. Now being able to open and take POST actions on both the URLs. Thanks Harsh and Pampy for taking out time and helping me out.